# How do I enable trackpad gestures (3 finger swipe, etc) on my Zenbook running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: touchpad, asus, gestures

New Linux user here, and I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my ASUS zenbook and realized my trackpad gestures no longer work. Scrolling and right click are fine, but I no longer have important ones such as 3 finger gestures and the 2 finger "go back a page" gesture. How do I get these working? I can figure out some technical solutions, but I'd prefer something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the default GNOME desktop, so these features are not exposed through the UI.
The good news is that there's [program](https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma) for that... but it may need to configure it manually. Luckily there are instructions, and they seem ubuntu-focused.

Comment: welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** Cound you please [edit] your answer and provide detailed steps on how to do that otherwise your answer might be deleted semi-automatically by the system...  **:-(**